# Why not represent discrete multivariate probability distribution as univariate?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

For example, a bivariate distribution over binary variables can be represented with a 2x2 matrix of probabilities:

\begin{bmatrix}
p_{0,0} 
&p_{0,1}
\\p_{1,0}
&p_{1,1}
\end{bmatrix}

The same information can be placed in a 4x1 vector:

\begin{bmatrix}
p_{0,0} 
\\p_{1,0}
\\p_{1,0}
\\p_{1,1}
\end{bmatrix}

This vector can be re-labeled:

\begin{bmatrix}
p_{0} 
\\p_{1}
\\p_{2}
\\p_{3}
\end{bmatrix}

Now the multivariateness is "hidden" and the distribution appears univariate.

Is there any reason not to implement such a relabeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the discrete case, there's nothing to prevent you from doing that. Effectively you're considering each tuple of results as a result in its own right. You might lose sight of some of the structure of the problem; whether this is useful will depend on the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @joriki the context is Bayes nets, so structure is certainly important.  I'm wondering if there's a way to not lose sight of structure when representing outcomes with {0,1,2,3} instead of {00,01,10,11}.  In the bivariate representation one has the opportunity to claim independence between the two RVs, while in the univariate representation one has no such opportunity.

Comment: @Werdna: My impression is that you're overrating this change of representation -- it's just a representation -- the way not to lose sight of the structure is just to keep it in mind -- there's not much to say about this unless you become more concrete about what you want to do and which aspect of either representation is making it harder or easier.